# ng-model is not selecting the value of ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to select the option in ng-option using ng-model.
I have all option mention in an array and table is coming from ng-repeat.

```
tr(ng-repeat='row in displayedCollection', style='padding:5px')
   td {{row.EMPID}} 
   td 
      span(data-ng-hide="editMode") {{row.value1.split(' ')[0]}}
      select.form-control.trkatn(name="value1",ng-options="item as item.label for item in dataty track by item.id", data-ng-model="row.value1.split(' ')[0]", data-ng-show="editMode")
   td 
      span(data-ng-hide="editMode") {{row.value2.split(' ')[0]}}
      select.form-control.trkatn(name="value2",ng-options="item as item.label for item in dataty track by item.id", data-ng-model="row.value2.split(' ')[0]", data-ng-show="editMode")
```

dataty array is as follow

```
$scope.dataty = [{id: 1,label: 'som1'},{id: 2,label: 'som2'}]
```

`rows` in `displayedCollection` is coming from database
for an example
`row.value1` will be somewhat `som2 15768243547687` and `row.value1.split(' ').[0]` will be somewhat `som2`

`row.value2` will be somewhat `som1 15768243547687` and `row.value2.split(' ').[0]` will be somewhat `som1`

Comment: No where in your question, have you written about the problem you are facing.

Comment: data-ng-model="row.value1.split(' ')[0]" will definitely not work. This is expected to the the REFERENCE to the model, it's not interpolated / evaluated.

Comment: @PierreGayvallet so how do i refer `row.value1.split(' ')[0]` to data-ng-model so that it will select an option